# Recover a deleted Tumblr post from Google Cache

Tags: tumblr, google-cache

I have accidentally deleted my Tumblr but when I look for it, I see in Google the beginning of my last article. As Google remember it, I would like to know if it is possible to get back at least the text of the article.

Comment: Have you tried to click green arrow near article address?

Answer (score 1):

Just type `cache:` before the URL in Chrome’s address bar and it goes straight to the cached version.

Or try https://archive.org/web/